# How to make a background color and icon on video

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

I want to make the shape like the following image.

On a video, I embed from youtube

the shape I want:

[image]
I tried to make div contains

```css
#lala {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  background-color: #000;
  z-index: 300000;
}
```

```html
<div id="lala">
  <iframe width="100%" height="550" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/jebTLd25Rjs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

but nothing happen :(

Comment: Add padding and you'll see your background color.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#lala {
    position: relative;
}
#lala:after {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.63);
    z-index: 300000;
    content: "";
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```